# How can I edit paginate options in DataTable Editor

Tags: datatables, editor

By default the pagination is limited to 10. How can I change this. I try to search in the manual or in the script and the option does not seem to exist.
Besides, a dropdown to select the nuber of items seems to be not provided.

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can set *page length* (number of rows in a page) attribute like this;

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

And this will directly affect the **pagination**.

Also; there are lots of [pagination alternatives](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html).